# Border is not showing correctly when i made a listing with div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have data listing section made with div. Each row in my listing contains

```
<div class="itemBox" style="width:25px;">4</div>
<div class="itemBox" style="width:60px; height: auto;"> CPT4</div>
<div class="itemBox" style="width:60px; height: auto;">43633</div>
<div class="itemBox" style="width:60px; height: auto;"></div>
```

Css for itemBox is

```
    .itemBox {
    border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
    min-height: 15px;
    padding: 5px 0;
   }
```

**When one itemBox div have larger text content the border in that row won't show  correctly** .Is there any way to fix this issue?.

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You mean the border is not at the end of the content?

Comment: Can you post your  entire code if it is not lengthy or create a fiddle if it is....

Comment: Yes . need to show at the end of each row ..

Comment: Created jsfiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/rejeeshthampi/n3cgoftv/1/

Comment: General observation posted in my answer, I believe if you use a table tag this will be much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. Or alternatively, if you only need to support newer browsers, use `flexbox`.

https://jsbin.com/qafomuzako/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">Short</div>
    <div class="cell">Short</div>
    <div class="cell">Short</div>
    <div class="cell">Longer input that spans multiple lines</div>
</div>

.table {
  display: table;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: none;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}

.cell::last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you border is not being applied properly is due to the fact that you are floating the divs with class .itemBox is in the last column. Hence it does not adjust to the previous divs that that are in single ul tag. In fact the divs that made the last column adjust to **their** own height instead of their "row"'s height

[fiddle here that shows the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/xf3oee0c/)

Add a `word-wrap` property to your `itemBox` class

Take out those divs that make the last column and include it in your span element your span element that is in your `li` tags. Do not float these divs

[fiddle here for a solution](https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/Ldh5e6nj/)